Why the number of samples given by `ffmpegio` differs using 2 methods?
I have an mp3 file at a sample rate value of 44100, let's name it a.mp3.
Using python library ffmpegio with the following code, i get a total amount of sample equal to 290704.
with ffmpegio.open(file, 'ra', blocksize = 16, sample_fmt = 'dbl') as file_opened:

        for i, indata in enumerate(file_opened):

            do some stuff
    print((i + 1) * 16)

But,
ffmpegio.probe.audio_streams_basic('a.mp3')[0]['nb_samples']
gives me 292608
How the difference between 292608 and 290704 could be explained?
I search in ffmpegio documentation, but found nothing that trigered my attention:
https://python-ffmpegio.github.io/python-ffmpegio/
Thanks.
I tried to get more information about how the total number of samples was calculated in ffmpegio.probe.audio_streams_basic()
Also, the difference does not seem to increase with increasing the length of the mp3 file.

What is 290704 ?

... in case you are relying in i, i changes accordingly to the given blocksize. I doubt that value is what you expect.

Hi, i is just a counter.
for i, val in enumerate([1, 2]): print(i, val)
Returns,
0 1
1 2

290704 is just the number of block samples times the amount of samples in one block

If MafMal is right and i and/or the loop depend on the blocksize, then i and indata seem not to be "samples"

(I'm the ffmpegio dev)
As far as I can tell, the most likely suspect is that audio_streams_basic() reporting incorrect nb_samples. audio_streams_basic computes nb_samples from ffprobe's outputs if ffprobe does not return nb_samples. It's calculation is rudimentary atm, only based on the duration timestamp, possibly ignoring start time and other timings.
Try
from pprint import pprint

pprint(ffmpegio.probe.full_details(file,select_streams=0))

and see if you see nb_samples in the stream info. If it's not included, please report the issue on GitHub, with cut-n-pasted stream info.
Also, you can try
fs, x = ffmpegio.audio.read(file)
print(x.shape)

to make sure the sample count matches that of the stream reader.
Finally, the read stream is guaranteed to return blocksize samples at a time except for the last block to address the posted comments.

Thank you for your response!
I will try that later.

Ok, so i do not see nb_samples from pprint(ffmpegio.probe.full_details(file,select_streams=0))

I have reported the issue.

ffmpegio.audio.read(file)[0].shape[0] is exactly what i wanted !
